# silverlight out of browser - icons

Tags: silverlight-3.0

Does anyone know how to change icons in Silverlight outofbrowser application?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Modify `AppManifest.xml` in your project:

```
<Deployment.ApplicationIdentity>
    <ApplicationIdentity
        ShortName="xxx"
        Title="xxx">
        <ApplicationIdentity.Blurb>
            xxx
        </ApplicationIdentity.Blurb>
        <ApplicationIdentity.Icons>
            <Icon Size="16x16">icons/16x16.png</Icon>
            <Icon Size="32x32">icons/32x32.png</Icon>
            <Icon Size="48x48">icons/48x48.png</Icon>
            <Icon Size="128x128">icons/128x128.png</Icon>
        </ApplicationIdentity.Icons>
    </ApplicationIdentity>
</Deployment.ApplicationIdentity>
```

Icons should be in png format images (build action set to Content)

You can read more [here](http://mokosh.co.uk/post/2009/04/21/silverlight-3-out-of-browser-oob-applications/).

Answer (score 1):

I Have New Idea To Implement This

1 . Click On Sliverlight Project

2 . Select Properties option

3 . Select First tab option Like Silverlight

4 . Click On Out-Of-Browser setting Option

5 . You can Set icons according to your request.......